# Update On-Topic Help with Links to Common SE Sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, migration, help-center

#### Current situation

Some sites that are very closely related to SO are omitted from the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.  Specifically, the sites below are not mentioned at all on that page.

- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

I feel that the lack of knowledge (and information) about these other Stack Exchange sites tends to create a lack of understanding for users for the proper site to post a question.

> If I can't post it *here*, where *can* I post it?

There's no real easy way to migrate, except to notify mods that it may fit better elsewhere. The flagging migration paths do not include any of those three options.

#### Proposal

We should add language to the SO help centre's [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to indicate that there are other sites for some of these things.

We could borrow some language from the other on-topic pages [Programmers On-Topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Code Review On-Topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [Code Golf On-Topic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to help users locate these sites. It would be beneficial for all of the SE sites mentioned, as it would help users find the appropriate site for their question and reduce the amount of off-topic content.  If we make it easy for users to **find the correct site** for their question, it would *hopefully* cut down on posts that are blatantly off-topic.

Ideally, this solution would cut down the number of posts that would need migration, so it would also help with the current migration problems.

#### Other considerations

I understand that Code Review is still a Beta site, maybe there could be an exception made for this extenuating circumstance, as far as mentioning it on the help page. Considering it's been around for [over 1600 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) I would think it's safe to assume that the topic is established enough to put SO/SE in the position to make a more formal link.  If they still refuse to do so - perhaps Code Review should be considered for graduation.

As for programmers, as [Simon and Snowman mention in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296714/update-on-topic-help-with-links-to-common-se-sites?noredirect=1#comment206299_296714), we could make [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815) more clear.

If I'm missing some larger picture explaining this lack of interconnection among Stack Exchange sites, please mention that in an answer.

Comment: Yes I like this idea.  If we expand the "__If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow__" (emphasis as is) section to include these other sites, it might help the off-topic questions.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's my main thought. I think that it would be significantly more helpful to **all** users. It would help people find where their topic would be more accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to Code Review is not likely to happen, because Code Review is not "graduated" yet - beta sites are not linked in the migration or other places. This may be changing now with this post: [Clarifying understanding of beta-site state](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/241497)... but I don't think so. A good solution woul dbe for Code Review to actually graduate ;-)

Comment: @rolfl Though I agree with you - it's hard for a beta site to graduate when many of the people posting questions that **could** be posted on it do not know it exists. The lack of awareness for that site is not helping it's graduation at all.

Comment: @EBrown - I completely agree with you on many levels, all I am saying is that SE folk have traditionally refused to make formal links between graduated and beta sites.

Comment: @rolfl Perhaps they should make an exception in this case, considering the close relationship the two topics share. It would most certainly make it easier to educate new users on it as well. Though, that doesn't explain the lack of education on the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @Kendra The newer version, [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182) is also a good read.

Comment: Yes, please reference **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)** rather than the toilet bowl article. It is more recent and accurate.

Comment: @EBrown is it even possible to educate people as to what's on topic on Programmers? To the best of my knowledge nobody understands what's on topic there. =;)-

Comment: While this suggestion is a good idea, it is important to note that currently, **about 90%** of all suggestions in comments to post at Programmers are **bad recommendations**. For Code Review, about 50% of all suggestions to post a question there are bad recommendations.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Perhaps if the community was more educated, those numbers would drop.

Comment: @RubberDuck It would be easier to explain Programmers as more of a site based around the **concepts of programming** and not any specific problems or issues.

Comment: @EBrown The classic problem is SO users interpreting "conceptual question" as "anything too broad/subjective to be answered on SO", when that often means it's just a bad question for any SE site.

Comment: I am very reluctant to add any suggestion that we should migrate conceptual questions to programmers. Why? Because most SO users have no idea what's on topic over there. We had to remove the migration route because of, quite frankly, the crap that was being migrated.

Comment: @EBrown Yes, I believe both the Code Review community and the Programmers community [are working on it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79408/you-are-being-watched-comments-of-interest)

Comment: @EBrown the guide for Stack Overflow is plenty clear. What I thought you were saying at first (and I agree with) is that there should be a guide in the **Stack Overflow help center** that says similar things to the Programmers guide.

Comment: @ChrisF that's fair.  If I'm not mistaken, this request is trying to avoid migrations in the first place.  Well ideally, since the user has read SO's help page, they will read the suggested alternate site's help page and only post on-topic stuff there.  Either way SO at least benefits by not having to deal with that quesiton.

Comment: @ChrisF That doesn't solve the issue - we need **more** information, not less. There needs to be **more help-center information** that describes, especially for those confused on the issue, what each site is for.

Comment: @Ixrec Again, the **more information** tactic would help resolve that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's the idea - I'm not necessarily saying migration paths *have* to be added, I'm more-or-less suggesting we update the appropriate help-centers with information assisting new users. The problem always lies in the fact that **very few** SO users know Programmers and Code Review exist.

Comment: @EBrown - The migration dialog has a link to the target's site help pages. Even with that there people still didn't read it.

Comment: @ChrisF You are missing my point, it's not **just** the people flagging/voting for migration that are the issue, if the question is a **good fit** for Code Review or Programmers, it shouldn't have been posted here to begin with. More help-center information could help with this. The graduation of Code Review (and/or the inclusion of information on it on SO) could most certainly allow people to find more **easily-accessed** information on what that site is for.

Comment: @ChrisF Also, in that case, maybe we should rethink the migration dialogue, and add information **directly within it** that describes the purpose. For example, the Migration Path Description for [Super User](http://superuser.com) is very ambiguous: `Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users`. The [on-topic for it](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) clearly lists **what is accepted**, unlike the migration dialogue.

Comment: On the Big Meta: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is that traditionally, graduated sites pretend that beta sites don't officially exist.  Therefore, the Stack Overflow Help Center doesn't mention Code Review and Code Golf.  I don't know whether that is a hard rule.  As Code Review becomes resigned to its perpetually [graduated](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/code-review-graduation)-but-[not-graduated](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/what-ever-happened-to-code-review-graduating) status, perhaps it may be time to bend that rule.  (Of course, the *right* thing to do is to just finish graduating Code Review.)

In any case, I would advise you to proceed methodically.  It is currently common practice for Stack Overflow users to close questions with comments like

> I vote to close this question because it would be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Sometimes that is the right advice, but for the [wrong reason](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/251568/148099).  It's not that I like being pedantic, but misunderstandings like this will lead to errors in judgement.

An important first step towards clarifying the relationship would be to better define what is on-topic for Stack Overflow.  Are code review requests actually off-topic on Stack Overflow?  The [Stack Overflow Help Center](/help/on-topic) actually doesn't explicitly say so.  So, before the Stack Overflow Help Center starts mentioning the Code Review site, I recommend adding some guidance as to

- what constitutes a request for a code review by Stack Overflow's standards, and
- whether code review requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow, and by what reason.

Once that wording is in place, it would be helpful to [educate Stack Overflow users](/q/253975/1157100).

All of that can be done without regard to the beta/non-beta status of Code Review.  I'd like to see it happen before taking the next step to mentioning Code Review, so as to avoid perpetuating the popular but misguided closing-because-it-is-a-better-fit-elsewhere reasoning.

Comment: I feel like this is a major part of the problem - how are we to encourage use of another site in the network, if we *refuse to recognize it* until it has completed graduation? It's an elitist policy - because SO has already graduated, we **are better** than Code Review. (Or so the attitudes/actions of the users would make it appear.)

Comment: Yes, code-reviews aren't on-topic. They aren't covered by "1. a specific programming problem, or 2. a software algorithm, or 3. software tools commonly used by programmers". Which means there's no need to list them in the list of exceptions which follows that.

Comment: @Deduplicator Many many many Code-Review like questions, on both Code Review and Stack Overflow (some that get suggested to be posted on CR instead, because of the reasons mentioned by 200_success above), *are* about algorithms.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: In the same way that they are all about characters, yes. He's only suggesting making that explicit instead of leaving it implicit.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg However, the difference is that Code Review is for examining code **that already works**, whereas Stack Overflow is more for troubleshooting code **that doesn't work**. Yes, there is a little overlap in some of the terminology, but if it were made more clear that the difference is that SO is for troubleshooting, and CR is geared towards optimization and performance tuning, then maybe we could make a better distinction on that front.

Comment: @Deduplicator So let's start a campaign to discourage "I vote to close this question because it is more suitable for Code Review" and encourage "This question is off-topic because there is no specific programming problem, just a general request to improve working code," which better explains the two sites' separate existence. This seems to be a common-enough case that it warrants specific guidance in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @200_success I completely agree. Similarly we should do something for Programmers as well, as there tends to be enough questions to warrant that as well.

Comment: “Traditionally, graduated sites pretend that beta sites don't officially exist.” Not only it doesn't make any sense, but that's the first time I hear of this, and I've been around. Is that some new “Stack Overflow pretends that beta sites don't officially exist” thing (I haven't been on MSO much lately)? http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic mentions [crypto.se], http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic mentions [expatriates.se], http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic mentions [cs.se] and [crypto.se], …